# raspberrypi time changes and then it hangs without any reason, can someone help. A beginner here

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero-w

Syslog data that I see , notice that time jumps back after this strange line is logged ^@^@^@^@^@. once this happens, raspberry Pi Zero W  becomes non- responsive and I have to restart to connect back to it via SSH. I am running headless Raspbian Buster Lite on it.

```
 Nov 29 02:06:01 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...

    Nov 29 02:06:01 raspberrypi CRON[1398]: (pi) CMD (sudo /bin/ping -c2 -I wlan0 8.8.8.8 >>/dev/null)

    Nov 29 02:06:02 raspberrypi systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service: Succeeded.

    Nov 29 02:06:02 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.

    ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^$

    Nov 29 01:59:50 raspberrypi systemd-fsck[103]: e2fsck 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)

    Nov 29 01:59:50 raspberrypi systemd-fsck[103]: Superblock last mount time is in the future.

    Nov 29 01:59:50 raspberrypi systemd-fsck[103]: #011(by less than a day, probably due to the hardware clock being incorrectly set)

    Nov 29 01:59:50 raspberrypi systemd-fsck[103]: rootfs: clean, 76212/1899328 files, 735052/7725184 blocks
```

Comment: Do you actually have a problem? If so ask about that.

Comment: @Milliways , Sorry, forgot to mention about that, once this happens, raspberry Pi Zero W  becomes non- responsive and I have to restart to connect back to it via SSH. I am running headless Raspbian Buster Lite on it.

Comment: The line of `^@^@^@^@^@^@` is due to the power being pulled. Nothing more. Your hanging system is like due to using all RAM and getting into swapping hell.